# gcc Boost template results in "defined in discarded section"

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, boost

I'm using gcc 4.7.4 20140401 to cross compile for an embedded ARM Cortex M4 (Pixhawk). I'm trying to get Boost Statechart working and I've come across an error that I can't resolve. Below is an of one them, there are many like this.

> `_ZTIN5boost12noncopyable_11noncopyableE' referenced in section`.rodata._ZTIN5boost10statechart13state_machineI15PositionControl15HoldingPositionSaIvENS0_25null_exception_translatorEEE[_ZTIN5boost10statechart13state_machineI15PositionControl15HoldingPositionSaIvENS0_25null_exception_translatorEEE]' of /home/nghia/Documents/catkin/Firmware/Build/px4fmu-v2_default.build//home/nghia/Documents/catkin/Firmware/src/modules/state_machine_boost/module.pre.o: defined in discarded section `.rodata._ZTIN5boost12noncopyable_11noncopyableE[_ZTIN5boost12noncopyable_11noncopyableE]' of /home/nghia/Documents/catkin/Firmware/Build/px4fmu-v2_default.build//home/nghia/Documents/catkin/Firmware/src/modules/state_machine_boost/module.pre.o

I've read through all the Stackoverflow posts regarding 'defined in discarded section', but haven't found any solution that works. This includes enabling/disabling -ffunction-sections, -fdata-sections, --gc-sections, optimization flags, and re-ordering the module.

Boost Statechart makes heavy use of template, which I suspect is causing the problem. Is gcc optimizing out stuff it thinks isn't being used?

**UPDATE:**
I've managed to come up with a bare minimal example that triggers the error above:

```
class dummy : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    int x;    
};

static dummy g_dummy;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem is with another module that was including Boost Statechart. Removing the Boost related code in the other module resolves all the compilation error. I'm guessing the linker doesn't like seeing multiple instance of Boost templates in different object files.